# function with equal upper and lower sums

Tags: integration

Which function f on [0,1] has equal lower and upper sum for each partition? I guess constant functions are the only such functions. Give me some hint to prove it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose firstly  that $f(0) \ne f(1)$ and WLG $f(0) \lt f(1)$ then for the simple partition $[0, 1]$ the upper and lower sums differ (upper is $\ge f(1)$, and lower $\le f(0)$), and so by contradiction, $f(0) = f(1) = $(say) $C$.

Now, suppose $0 < x  < 1$ and that $f(x) \ne C$ WLG assume that $f(x) \gt C$. Then consider the partition $[0, x]; [x, 1]$. Upper sum is $ \ge f(x)$, while lower sum is $ \le C$, so again they differ and by contradiction,  $f(x) = C$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$

Putting the two together, $f(x) = C$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose f is not constant. Then WLG we can assume that f (a) less than f (b) for different a and b. 
For the partition  P :a,b  the upper and lower sums are different. 
So no such a & b exist. Hence f is constant.